# How to wrap the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have used a horizontal collection view for scrolling the UILabel. In my array i have 30 item. When  i scroll to the 30th item it should again show the first item, its like a circular scroll. Following is my code and image which i want to achieve.

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
     return self.waitListArray.count;
  }

- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 WaitListWarningTimeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCollectionViewIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblWaitingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@m", self.waitListArray[indexPath.row]];

    if ([self.waitListArray[indexPath.row] intValue]==0) {

    cell.lblWaitingTime.text = @"Off";
}

if (indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex)
{
    cell.lblWaitingTime.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
else
{
    cell.lblWaitingTime.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can refer iCarousel it has some great examples of the functionality you want. Here is the link

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)